# Submit active form on radio button click

Tags: php, forms, yii2

I have a listbox widget in a Yii2 form, looking like this:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'filter')->listBox([
    'odd' => 'Odd products',
    'even' => 'Even products'
])
```

Is there a way I can submit the form when the user clicks on one of those radio buttons?

Comment: You could write jQuery to do the task.

Comment: jQuery isn't required, plain JavaScript would suffice.

Comment: You should try this `echo $form->field($model, 'filter')->radioList([
    'odd' => 'Odd products',
    'even' => 'Even products'
], ['onclick' => 'this.form.submit()'])`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $form->field($model, 'filter')->radioList([
    'odd' => 'Odd products',
    'even' => 'Even products'
])
```